# Drupal, faceted search and google api

Tags: drupal, google-api, faceted-search

A recent task I have to figure out, gives me some hard time thinking about it, so I decided to share it with you guys :)

My Drupal 6.x application is made using modules like: faceted-search, views, CCK. 
Now I would like to add some additional functionalities connected with faceted-search module... And here comes the fun :)

I want to give my app user availability to search with additional field "distance".

So user-story looks like that: 
User A adds item to application, he fills field: city, street etc. 
User B decides to search some item in app. During search he decided that he do not want to anything in different city, so he decided that the distance should me 5km from his location (in his profile - city, street).

And the question in... How can I bite that, any suggestion, modules?

thx
tzim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Apache Solr will perfectly fit for it. It has very good Drupal module as well.

Comment: Sorl seems to be the only solution. faceted-search is not ready to be used on sites with more then 100 users IMO.